# Changing Many Null Textboxes to 0 in Access

Tags: database, ms-access, vba

I have a problem with changing all textboxes in a form with Null to a Value 0.0 after Lost Focus. Specifically, if the textbox is blank after pressing tab it would revert back to 0 since it affects calculations in the other part of the form. Writing the code for every textbox event procedure (57 or so boxes) seems tedious and the names for all the boxes are different.

I was wondering if there was an efficient way to go about changing the textbox value after losing focus easily rather than changing the event procedure for every textbox in the form.

Thanks

Comment: What kind of application is this ? Windows / Web ???

Comment: It's just for Windows. A form to fill out when you open access

Comment: I don't believe there is anyway that you can call the "Lost Focus" event on all textboxes without individually setting the procedures for each one.  Have you thought about defaulting them all to 0.0 to start with?

Comment: I have tried defaulting but the problem remains that when I tab to the next textbox, if the box is blank, it remains blank

Comment: I see what you mean.  The only other suggestion I would have is to give each control a tag, then when you are about to calculate loop through all controls and any that have the tag set  them to zero if empty.  Though that becomes almost as tedious as just setting it in each Lost Focus event.

Answer (score 0):

Figured I would give an example along with my comments.  You could use something along these lines:

```
Public Function DefaultToZero(frm As Form)

    Dim ctrl As Access.Control

    For Each ctrl In frm
        If ctrl.Tag = "Default" Then
            If Nz(ctrl.Value, "") = "" Then
                ctrl.Value= "0.0"
            End If
        End If
    Next ctrl

End Function
```

Then you just select all controls while in design mode and set the tag to 'Default'.  Not the best answer but I don't really see any other options besides using each "Lost Focus" event.